# How to find the fork point from a named branch pattern?

Tags: git

We have branches 'main/master' and many branches 'release_*.*'.

In git, is it possible to find the hash of the fork point from ANY of those not knowing which one it was forked from?

I am playing around with `git merge-base --fork-point {mybranch}` and it just shows last fork point but that fork point may or may not be `release_*.*` depending on what the developer is doing.

I know I can do `git merge-base {mybranch} main` and it shows the fork point of main but what I want is more like `git merge-base {mybranch} {main or release_*.*}` to get the last important fork point.

ie. we know a PR will be created to merge back into the closest fork point of one of those names.  I am not sure hashes have the branch names though or how to get the branch name through a hash as I could keep asking for last fork point I think in a loop?

Comment: Branch names are not stuff that git stores in commit's metadata. Branches points to commits and commits point to more commits to make up their history.

Comment: An implication from @eftshift0's comment, which may not be immediately obvious, is that many commits are on *many* branches simultaneously. It's not clear what you mean by "*important* fork point" here; the merge base commit(s) is/are the "best" shared commits as defined by the [Lowest Common Ancestor algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs).